# Spring Security SAML with existing J2EE Application (Not-Spring based)

Tags: jakarta-ee, spring-security, spring-saml

I have an existing J2EE based application which is using standard J2EE and not Spring framework. I want to implement the Spring SAML based federation in the existing application without changing the application to Spring framework (as it will require a lot of effort)
As I am new to Spring framework, is there any way where I can just integrate the Spring based federation in my application as an additional functionality (like adding the Spring federation application as Jar and exposing some APIs and using them in the J2EE application)?

Answer (score 1):

SAML protocol is not directly related to Spring, as it is an open-standard for authentication and authorization.
If you already have a Java EE based application, you should be able to use SAML for your application server without using Spring.
For instance, You can find how to use SAML-based authentication with Jboss EAP 6 on [this page](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en/red-hat-jboss-enterprise-application-platform/6.4/single/how-to-setup-sso-with-saml-v2/)

Comment: I prefer using Spring SAML extension as it provides a lot of Configuration possibilities.